# Find list of Subscriptions from azure Topic

Tags: azure, servicebus

Is it possible to find a list of Subscriptions on a Service Bus Topic?

I want to be able to find the list and then loop through it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using C#, you can do something like the following:

```
private void EnumerateTopics()
{
    var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(c_ConnectionString);
    const string topicName = "testtopic";

    var subscriptions = namespaceManager.GetSubscriptions(topicName);

    // do stuff with subscriptions
}
```

That's obviously all synchronous, but there are corresponding async versions of the calls (`GetSubscriptionsAsync`, for example).  The subscriptions object is an `IEnumerable<SubscriptionDescription>`, which'll let you get at any other aspect of the subscription that you might want to use.

First you'll need to:

1. add the corresponding "Windows Azure Service Bus" NuGet package to your solution
2. add a reference to "Microsoft.ServiceBus" to the corresponding csproj
3. and obviously drop the using statement `using Microsoft.ServiceBus;`
   in your .cs file

Your connection string will be exactly what you pull from the Azure Management Portal, roughly along the lines of:
`Endpoint=sb://[namespacename].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=[key]`

There are similarly easy-to-use libraries available for other languages too.